# Encrypt Data in one "slot" in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, encryption, insert

I read over a great tutorial on how to encrypt the data using a symmetrical key in one column. 
[Click here to view it.](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/sql/IntroductionToSQLServerEncryptionAndSymmetricKeyEncryptionTutorial.aspx)

This has helped me set up a column for encryption, which is what I need. My problem is that I will constantly be updating rows in my database - so copying over one whole original column to the encrypted columm like the tutorial shows doesn't work. Is there a way that I can insert a value that is given to me (using C#/asp) and direclty encrypt it as I insert it into the database, rather than having to place it in one column and copying it over, and then dropping the other column?

Comment: Encrypting data with .NET is pretty straightforward as is storing in the database. But I think you need to be able to let the db read and return that value as well... is that right?

Comment: Are you asking if its possible to encrypt the data for a particular column before you insert the data into the database?  I am not sure the reason you would use SQL Server to do the encryption.

Comment: there are many reasons to use sql for encryption as all keys are kept on the server (plus others). the keys are kept out of config files, etc. Its also fairly seamless and the application usually doesnt have to worry about it especially if implemented in a proc.

Comment: How about this?  http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithcombs/archive/2005/11/24/415079.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call EncryptByKey on your data to encrypt You don't need another column. In this case it has to be included in your SQL which should be a parameterized query or a stored procedure.

Insert into Whatever
YourEncryptedData
Values ( EncryptByKey(...))
You may have top open your key first depending on your implementation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174361.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the certificate open do do the encryption.  This is from the page you linked to:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY TestTableKey
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE EncryptTestCert

UPDATE TestTable
SET EncryptSecondCol = ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('TestTableKey'),SecondCol)
```

Inserting works the same:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY TestTableKey
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE EncryptTestCert

INSERT INTO TestTable (FirstCol, EncryptSecondCol)
VALUES (6, ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('TestTableKey'),'Sixth'))
```

You can execute the open key command before doing your insert or create a stored procedure to do the insert.